# Azure free storage

Tags: .net, azure

hello
is there free storage on Azure so i can test my program ?if there how can i access it?

and if there are example n it i hope to guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an MSDN subscription you can sign up via the Subscribers portal on the MSDN web site.

There's more here http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/offers/

Answer (score 4):

Check out the "Introductory Special" http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/offers/ It is essentially a free account. You have to go through the whole process and sign up, but once set up you get to use it free as long as you don't go past the limits. When/if you do then you just pay for what you use above the free usage.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Free Windows Azure platform 30 day pass (in US only). No credit card required. You can test your application on Windows Azure and SQL Azure for free.  More detail on http://bit.ly/gCwHTf.